# golang mkdir /usr/local/go/pkg/mod permission denied

Tags: linux, go, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2, goland

OS: Windows 11 WSL2;
IDE: Goland Latest

I am trying to open my IDE Goland, but I get this error when the IDE tries to index my project.

```
warning: GOPATH set to GOROOT (/usr/local/go) has no effect
go: mkdir /usr/local/go/pkg/mod: permission denied
go: github.com/MyCompany/common-backend@v1.0.56: mkdir /usr/local/go/pkg/mod: permission denied
```

though, I already set my go like this

```
 export GOROOT=/usr/local/go
 export GOPATH=$HOME/go
 export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin
```

is that anything I miss for my WSL for **Go** Path?

Comment: Never set GOROOT. Make sure Your IDE knows about your GOPATH (or unset it).

Comment: What do you have in the IDE settings under Go | GOROOT and Go | GOPATH?

Answer (score 0):

Faced the similar issue of permission denied error while installing `go analysis tools`.
The problem for me was while installing golang that means extracting the content of golang tar file i used `sudo`, something like below

```bash
sudo tar -C ./ -xzf go1.21.4.linux-amd64.tar.gz
```

this assigned the `go` binary dir to root user as owner and vs code is running from my own user which caused this error.

Re-installing `go` without `sudo` should fix the problem.
Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

if you have this problem on linux 
go inside your go installation directory 
the default installation is `/usr/local` 
and change the permissions `sudo chmod -R 775 .`

Answer (score -3):

Step 1: Open your terminal check GOPATH

[image: mrone.inc]

```
go env | grep GOPATH
```

Step 2: Copy your GOPATH and them to ~/.zshrc

[image: mrone.inc]

[image: mrone.inc]

```
sudo gedit ~/.zshrc
```

Step 3: Save and reboot bash

[image: mrone.inc]

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

Alternative: Make the current user as a root

[image: mrone.inc]

[image: mrone.inc]

```
sudo chown <user> -R  /root/
```

Comment: not the way to solve it.